# Set Fog Color to match dynamic skybox in URP

Tags: unity, graphic-effects, skybox, fog

I have a dynamically changing procedural skybox. That's a procedural skybox with dynamic day and night cycle.
The main directional light keeps rotating over time by a script, to achieve the day/night cycle.

I want environment to fade out into the skybox back color.

Fog works the best, but problem is that overtime when the skybox changes color, the fog color mismatches. At night, the fog is bright blue.
I want it to always fit with the skybox. Can I edit the fog settings to always take a color from the skybox?

I'm using Unity's Default Fog from Lightning settings. Settings are Exponential Squared with 0.025 density.

[image: Fog settings in Lightning Tab]

Also is there any completely alternate approach that gets the job done?
Since the only reason I need it is, to the fade out objects and just fade out the far away objects.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a value to `RenderSettings.fogColor` in script periodically to update the colour of the fog?

Comment: That's the approach I'm going forward with, but how will I constantly get the color from the sky?

Comment: That depends on the method you're using to change the colour of the sky. Can you edit your question to document how the skybox colours are determined?

Comment: @DMGregory It is a procedural skybox with dynamic day and night cycle.

Comment: Be sure to edit your question to show us how you've set up the procedural skybox with its dynamic day and night cycle. There's more than one way to do this, so don't assume a reader will know which one you used unless you show them.

Comment: Done @DMGregory